# "Cannot read property 'type' of null" when building library module that leverages InjectionToken

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, build

**Resolved**

I can't explain the significance of the InjectionToken in the mix, but I did find the source of the error.  When I copied some of my old code from the previous incarnation of this project I pulled the @angular imports with it.  I'm on windows, and somehow I managed to have 1 path that had `@Angular/router` instead of `@angular/router`.  No idea how it worked in V6 as a monorepo, but it crashed with this useless error message in V7 library build.

---

## Original Post

I'm attempting to create an InjectionToken in a library module so I can pass my app environment variables into it.  As soon as the service attempts to import the exported token I get **"Cannot read property 'type' of null"** during build.  Is this the only way to get env vars into a lib?  Or did I do something wrong?

*Versions*

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.10.3
@angular-devkit/core               7.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.0.3
@angular/cli                       7.0.3
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.0.3
@schematics/angular                7.0.3
@schematics/update                 0.10.3
ng-packagr                         4.4.0
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.1.3
webpack                            4.19.1
```

*my.module.ts*

```
import { MyHeaderService } from './my-header.service';
import { MyHeaderComponent } from './my-header.component';
export const env = new InjectionToken<any>('env');

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule
   ],
  declarations: [MyHeaderComponent],
  exports: [MyHeaderComponent]
})

export class MyHeaderModule {
  static forRoot(envVars: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyHeaderModule,
      providers: [
        MyeaderService,
        {
          provide: env,
          useValue: envVars
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

*my-header.service.ts*

```
/* lines with <-- indicate they can be removed and build,
 but of course it wont have the env vars */

import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { env } from './my-header.module';  // <--

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyHeaderService {
  constructor(@Inject(env) ENV: any) { // <--
    console.log(ENV); // <--
  } // <--
}
```

Comment: I think you have a circular reference issue since both of the files are importing things exported from the other. Try to pull out the injection token into a third file (i.e. `my.model.ts`) and import that injection token into each file and the error should be fixed.

Comment: Check your typo `MyeaderService`